# Is it correct to leverage a stream writer WriteLineAsync with WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, streamwriter

I have a snippet of code that is writing to a memory stream in an asynchronous way (.NET Standard 2.1)

- Create a list of hot tasks, one per a line
- Then await when all of them will be finished
- Flush the writer buffer to the memoryStream at the end

Code:

```
await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

var recordTasks = stringRecordsToWrite.Select(r => writer.WriteLineAsync(r));

await Task.WhenAll(recordTasks);

await writer.FlushAsync();

var result = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

**Questions**

There are a couple of questions that bothering me:

1. There were reports that time to time some records had been skipped.
   Thus, I wonder, could such implementation be the root cause. I've tried to reproduce the issue locally, but, unfortunately, no success
2. Also Resharper highlights that 'writer' (within SELECT statement) is a captured variable and disposed in outer scope. Can it be a problem?

Or those are false traces, and the implementation is fine, and I should try to found the reason out in other place

**P.s** The code snippet that, for attempt to reproduce the issue, but, as result a file about 250 MB size, and still no evidence of the issue
...

```
 internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var records = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<RecordsToWrite>>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                var recordKey = $"test-{i}";

                records.Add(recordKey, default);

                var itemRecords = new List<RecordsToWrite>();

                for (var x = 0; x < 500; x++)
                {
                    itemRecords.Add(new RecordsToWrite
                    {
                        Tracking = $"{recordKey}-Track-Ref-{x}"
                    });
                }

                records[recordKey] = itemRecords;
            }


            var resultAsBytes = new List<byte>();
            var randomizer = new Random();

            foreach (var kv in records)
            {
                await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

                var recordsToWrite = kv.Value;

                var writingRecordsTasks = recordsToWrite.Select(x =>
                {
                    var randomLengthString = randomizer.Next(100, 5000);

                    return writer.WriteLineAsync($"track-ref-{x.Tracking}, " +
                                                 $"now in ticks: {DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}, " +
                                                 $"content: {new string(GetRandomLetter(), randomLengthString)}");
                });

                await Task.WhenAll(writingRecordsTasks);

                await writer.FlushAsync();

                resultAsBytes.AddRange(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultAsBytes.ToArray());
            await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("PathToAFile.txt", new[] { content });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static char GetRandomLetter() => (char)('a' + new Random().Next(0, 26));
    }
```

Comment: The StreamWriter isn't thread safe. so I wouldn't recommend launching multiple concurrent tasks on it.

Comment: "I've a snippet of code, that writing a file" - this doesn't write to a file. It's all in memory.

Comment: 1. Looking at the documentation I see a couple things of note: `StreamWriter` is [not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0#remarks), but `WriteLineAsync()` [throws when the instance is busy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writelineasync?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamwriter-writelineasync(system-string)). 2. Not a problem here, since all deferred access to the instance will be finished when `await Task.WhenAll(recordTasks);` returns. 3. This feels like a dumb idea in general.

Comment: @ESG  Maybe there is any thought how to reproduce the issue?  some scenarios, it need for QA team :)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Maybe there is any thought how to reproduce the issue?  Some scenarios, it need for QA team :)

Comment: Have you tried a huge amount of very long lines?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yep, I've  generated a pretty big memory stream and then put it down to a file, as result file was about 500 mb, but not occurrences of the issue. No skipped rows, ever more ordering was fine

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I've added the draft code snippet, how I tried to reproduce the issue, but no success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a *single* stream. It doesn't really make sense to write to it asynchronously in parallel - any number of things could go wrong. I don't even know what `MemoryStream`'s thread safety is like, and I can't see any documentation about that. The [documentation for `StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0) explicitly states:

> By default, a StreamWriter is not thread safe. See TextWriter.Synchronized for a thread-safe wrapper.

I would strongly advise you to just iterate sequentially, e.g.

```cs
foreach (var item in stringRecordsToWrite)
{
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Jon Skeet, maybe you can suggest how to reproduce the issue ? I need it for QA team :)

Comment: @AllmanTool: Not really, without quite a lot of experimentation myself. I'd start off just writing a console app though, using your current code with thousands of lines, and check the result afterwards. That *might* reproduce it - I don't know.

Comment: ok, anyway thanks a lot, I also had a feeling that the implementation is not correct, but should reproduce it to have a robust argument for QA team

Comment: Jon (or maybe @AllmanTool) could you clarify what "levering a stream" means in the title of the post?

Comment: leverage = using (typo)

Comment: `StreamWriter` calls `(Value)Task WriteAsync(...)` on the underlying stream. `MemoryStream` `WriteAsync` is not ever async ([.NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/7c6cbea58a012b83.html)/[Core](https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/R/118b66014b026e3a.html)). There is no race condition and only ever one thread until the `File.WriteAllLinesAsync`.

Comment: @Johnbot: It doesn't help that the question has changed significantly since I answered it :( Even if it turns out there's no parallelism here, I would still personally avoid the current code, due to relying on implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the missing lines to no avail. I just seems to work even when writing more than 10,000 lines totalling to almost 1GB of data.

This is my test:

```cs
static async Task<string> Write(int n) {
    var records = Enumerable
        .Range(0, n)
        .Select(i => string.Join(',', Enumerable.Repeat(i, n)));
    await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    
    // Will succeed.
    var tasks = records.Select(r => writer.WriteLineAsync(r));
    
    // Will cause failure. See notes below.
    //var tasks = records.Select(r => Task.Run(() => writer.WriteLine(r)));
    
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
    var bytes = stream.ToArray();
    var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
    return str;
}

const int N = 14000;
var result = await Write(N);
result
    .Split(Environment.NewLine)
    .Take(N) // skip last newline
    .ForEach((l, i) => Debug.Assert(
        l == string.Join(',', Enumerable.Repeat(i, N)),
        $"Line {i} is invalid: '{l[..10]}'"));
```

The lines always had the correct order and content.

`StreamWriter.WriteLineAsync(r)` checks if there currently is another async write task running and throws in that case. But I wasn't able to provoke that exception.

If I create the write tasks with `Task.Run(() => writer.WriteLine(r))` then the result is no longer deterministic. For small values of `N` the line order will be scrambled. For higher values an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown somewhere in `StreamWriter.FlushAsyncInternal()`. Here's the stackstrace:

```
at System.IO.StreamWriter.<FlushAsyncInternal>g__Core|76_0(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.DisposeAsyncCore()
at UserQuery.<Main>g__Write|4_0(Int32 n), line 18
at UserQuery.<Main>g__Write|4_0(Int32 n), line 18
at UserQuery.Main(), line 22
```

## Conclusion?

It looks like `StreamWriter` does a good job managing concurrent writes when the async interface is being used.

However, since it's not guaranteed to do that in the future and we can't even be 100% sure it does so now, I would not rely on it. Especially since utilizing its async interface safely can be done with minor code changes:

```cs
foreach (var r in stringRecordsToWrite)
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(r);
```

Comment: I guess that the reason that the `await Task.WhenAll(records.Select(r => writer.WriteLineAsync(r)));` is not failing is because all the `WriteLineAsync` operations are actually synchronous, because they are writing in an in-memory stream. You could verify this by checking the status of the `tasks` before awaiting them. I bet that all are completed upon creation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, that's what I assume too. `StringWriter` is synchronizing all async writes. Your assumption is correct: doing `Debug.Assert(tasks.All(t => t.IsCompleted))` before `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` will *not* fail.

Comment: It's not `StreamWriter` doing anything. It's `MemoryStream` not supporting async. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Cool, thanks for your investigation !